# Can Rich Text features be configured per user?

Tags: editor, tinymce, wysiwyg

There are obviously different types of users (from power-users to casual authors).

WordPress's Rich Text editor is based on TinyMCE - which has [a lot of features](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php).  Most of these features are disabled, by default, inside WordPress to create a friendlier (and safer) editing experience.  However, some power-users would prefer to use these extra TinyMCE features.

Is it possible to enable or disable various Rich Text features (tables, layers, styles, etc) per user?  How is this done?   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

look here [tinymce and users](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/add-cut-copy-and-paste-buttons-to-the-tinymce-editor/) and add something similar to your themes functions.php and maybe work on that by wrapping it with a custom role / capability which you assign to your trusted users:

```
if (current_user_can( 'have_tiny_mce_options' ) { tinymce options here }
```

the page example only shows 3 options but im sure that this can be improved